# Multiple UI elements from a table into an array

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am writing Selenium tests in Java where my script is firstly running a query against source system and gathering expected results. For this example my query is returning 4 member numbers that I then want to cross reference with a table on the UI to ensure that these 4 member numbers appear on a table. I also need to ensure that no more or less than these 4 member numbers are showing on the UI. The query may well return say 3 or 5 member numbers when the source system data changes so I need my test to be smart enough to know how many member numbers to look for based on the query results.

I'm thinking my approach to assert the query results against UI is to get both data sets into an array and run a assert equals to ensure they match each other.

My UI is as follows:

```
<tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="member in searchresult" class="ng-scope odd" role="row">
            <td class="ng-binding sorting_1">27002</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Test</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Test</td>
            </td>
        </tr><tr data-ng-repeat="member in searchresult" class="ng-scope even" role="row">
            <td class="ng-binding sorting_1">55691</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Standard</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">PGY2 TESTED</td>
            </td>
        </tr><tr data-ng-repeat="member in searchresult" class="ng-scope odd" role="row">
            <td class="ng-binding sorting_1">58716</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Standard</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">PGY3 TESTED</td>
            </td>
        </tr><tr data-ng-repeat="member in searchresult" class="ng-scope even" role="row">
            <td class="ng-binding sorting_1">95362</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">Standard</td>
            <td class="ng-binding">STUDENT tested</td>
            </td>
        </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

You can see the 4 member numbers always show in the class "ng-binding sorting_1". I'm wondering how I can write locators to grab each of these and put them into an array.

Also open to hear different approaches if this isn't the way to go for this check.

Comment: Do you have a table id as I can see closing tag for table?

Comment: There is a method in [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/) that lets you **findElements** on a page and returns a List. Maybe try reading the documentation?

Comment: Hi @Prany I do have a table ID. It's DataTables_Table_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `driver.findElements()` to get all tds in first table column.

```
String locator = "tbody > tr[data-ng-repeat='member in searchresult'] > td.sorting_1";

List<WebElement> tds = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(locator));

ArrayList<String> memberNums = new ArrayList<String>()

for(WebElement ele : tds) {
  memberNums.add(ele.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to iterate each row of the table. I hope you can relate to it now

```
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.Id("DataTables_Table_0"));


    // Now using Iterator we will iterate all elements
    Iterator<WebElement> iter = rows.iterator();

    // this will check whether list has some element or not
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        // Iterate one by one
        WebElement item = iter.next();

        // get text
        String label = item.getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

It will load all the values inside the td.

```
    List<WebElement> tableElements =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody//*");

    ArrayList<String> tdDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (WebElement tableElement: tableElements ) {
             tdDetails.add(tableElement.getText());

     }
```

If you want to get all the value inside the td class="ng-binding sorting_1

need to follow the below steps.

```
String attributeValue = "ng-binding sorting_1";
List<WebElement> tableElements =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody//*");

        ArrayList<String> tdDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (WebElement tableElement: tableElements ) {

                if(tableElement.getAttribute("class")!=null && tableElement.getAttribute("class")==attributeValue){

                      tdDetails.add(tableElement.getText());
                }


         }
```